# Handle Custom Event of User Control Contained in Repeater

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a user control inside a repeater and a custom event is raised by that user control but I do not know how to handle that event.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
    Protected Sub MyFancyEventRasied(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyFancyUserControl.MyFancyEvent   
        'do something fancy 
    End Sub
```

But I can't do this because the user control is inside of the repeaters ItemTemplate. How can you handle the event of a control inside of an ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ItemTemplate>
...
    <uc1:MyFancyUserControl OnMyFancyEvent="MyFancyEventRasied" ... />
...
</ItemTemplate>
```

and

```
Protected Sub MyFancyEventRasied(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'do something fancy 
End Sub
```